# Why is my button as a toggle not working when I try to update the state of the button?

Tags: arduino, toggle

When I try to change the state of the button after it is pressed, nothing works. I do this with the line `prev = current;`

```
#include <Servo.h>;

//HIGH not pressed
//LOW pressed

int pushD3 = 3;
int pushD4 = 4;
int pushD5 = 5;
int pushD6 = 6;
int val4 = 0;
int val5 = 0;
int ledPin = 13;
int prev = 0;
int current = 0;
Servo ZServo;

void setup() {
  ZServo.attach(9);
  pinMode(pushD3, INPUT_PULLUP);
  digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
  pinMode(pushD4, INPUT_PULLUP);
  digitalWrite(4, HIGH);
  pinMode(pushD5, INPUT_PULLUP);
  digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
  pinMode(pushD6, INPUT_PULLUP);
  digitalWrite(6, HIGH);
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  if (digitalRead(3) == LOW) {
    current = 1 - current;
  }
  if (current == 1 && prev == 0) {
    checkButtons_slow();
    delay(100);
  }
  if (current == 0 && prev == 1) {
    //ZServo.write(110);
    delay(500); //half a second
  }
  prev = current;
}

void checkButtons_slow() {
  val4 = digitalRead(pushD4);
  val5 = digitalRead(pushD5);
  if (val4 == LOW) {
    ZServo.write(87);
  } else if (val5 == LOW) {
    ZServo.write(99);
  } else {
    ZServo.write(91); //GUESSED ON 92; SHOULD TECHNICALLY BE 90
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't configure any pins. Where is `checkButtons_slow()` defined? What is supposed to happen?

Comment: @stevieb I've done that but I didn't put it in the code because I'm pretty sure it is correct. Edit shows all of it.

Comment: Thanks for the update. It's always best to show your entire sketch, or else at least a minimal example with all of the necessary code to exactly reproduce your issue. See [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I not able to call this method after I push a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44891298/why-am-i-not-able-to-call-this-method-after-i-push-a-button)

Comment: @gre_gor yes it's the same question posted again but no answer was accepted before.

Comment: It's a different question that relates to my previous one. @gre_gor

Answer (score 0):

You update your toggle state even when your button is not pushed.  That's why the logic doesn't work.  You also need to keep track of when the button is released for the toggle button logic.

You may also be the next victim of switch bounce.  A typical switch will not go cleanly from open to close, and can produce small, quick open/close signals when pushed (and released).  While this doesn't affect much simple pressed/depressed buttons operation, it is a killer for multiple states switches.

An easy way to avoid this is to limit the rate at which you read the switches.  I've found that a 30ms rate is pretty good.

```
int last_time = 0;
bool was_pushed = false;

void loop() {

  if (millis() - last_time > 30)  // filter out signal bounce.
  {
    last_time = millis();
    if (digitalRead(3) == LOW) 
    {
      if (!was_pushed)            // prevent toggling until button is released.      
        current = !current;
      was_pushed = true;  
    }
    else
    {
      was_pushed = false;
    }
    if (current != prev)
    {
       prev = current;           // keep the previous toggle state only on change.
       if (current) 
       {
         checkButtons_slow();
         delay(100);
       }
       else
       {
         //ZServo.write(110);
         delay(500); //half a second
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If I replace my code with this, then nothing happens at all. Although, if I replace `checkButtons_slow();` with `ZServo.write(80);` then once I click a button, the servo moves because of the `ZServo.write(80);`

Comment: This is not a complete sketch.  You still have to include your current setup() .

Comment: I know. I just replaced my loop() with that.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an Arduino with me today.

Answer (score 0):

I found your implementation and Michael's a bit confusing, why not doing:

```
bool state = false;
bool buttonPressed = false;
void loop(){
    if (digitalRead(3) == LOW && !buttonPressed){
        state=!state;
        buttonPressed = true;
    }
    if(digitalRead(3) == HIGH){
        buttonPressed = false;
    }

    // Then your logic
    if (state) {
    checkButtons_slow();
    delay(100);
    } else{
        //ZServo.write(110);
        delay(500); //half a second
    }
}
```